# R shiny: Add Konami Code inside a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, secret-key

Bonjour!

I wonder how to "easily" implemant the Konami code in any R shiny app

INPUT (from user keyboard  on the R shiny app page)
Arrow UP, UP, DOWN, DOWN , LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT, B, A

OUTPUT
- Add a fun image on the dashboard
(- Change color of the app)

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973549/r-shiny-key-input-binding ; or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675059/keyboard-shortcuts-to-trigger-reactive-flows-in-r-shiny ?

Comment: yeah maybe but my knowledge of HTML and JS is very limited

Comment: Maybe someone could show me a basic code of shiny app which display an image on the dashboard if the user enter the konami code.. 
Man, I am making a shiny app and so many hours into it  that I definitively want to add a joke like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Shiny key input binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973549/r-shiny-key-input-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> library(shiny)
> runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
>   verbatimTextOutput("results"),
>   verbatimTextOutput("allInputs"),
>   tags$script('
>               $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
>               Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", e.which);
>               });
>               ') 
> )
> , server = function(input, output, session) {
>
>   output$results = renderPrint({
>     input$mydata
>   })
>
>   keysPressed <- reactiveVal()
>
>   observeEvent(input$mydata, {
>     keysPressed(c(keysPressed(), input$mydata))
>   })
>
>   output$allInputs = renderPrint({
>     keysPressed()
>   })
>
> }
> ))
> ```
>
> > ismirsehregal who helped me on the code I found 
> >     [Is there a way in R shiny to concatenate all values taken by an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706132/is-there-a-way-in-r-shiny-to-concatenate-all-values-taken-by-an-input)

My final code merging all hints:

### UI.R (inside body)

```
          tags$script('
                   pressedKeyCount = 0;
                      $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                      Shiny.onInputChange("pressedKey", pressedKeyCount++);
                      Shiny.onInputChange("pressedKeyId", e.which);
                      });'
            ),
```

### SERVER.R (somewhere)

```
keysPressed <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$pressedKey, {
  keysPressed(c(keysPressed(), input$pressedKeyId))
})

output$secret <- renderUI({
  secretCode = keysPressed()
  if(length(secretCode)>=10)
  secretCode = secretCode[(length(secretCode)-9):length(secretCode)]
  trueCode = c(38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65)
  if(isTRUE(all.equal(secretCode,trueCode))){
    HTML('<center><img src="4BA140A6A75546D791B01BC0BA9E00A2.png"></center>')
    }
})
```

c(38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65) corresponds to famous konami code sequential key inputs